# Eclipse & JSF: Library linking

Tags: eclipse, jsf

Using Eclipse Helios, I'd like to develop a JSF based application. I tried to work through a [tutorial](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/jsf/docs/tutorial/JSFTools_1_0_tutorial.html). Even though I thought to have installed all the required stuff from the repo, in the Webeditor I have no Palette called JSF or kinda.

Furthermore, I cannot even add the library stated in the tutorial (in the first screenshot), because I don't have a subitem "Libraries" in the JSF-Part at left.

See the screenshot:
[image: screenshot]

Already tried to download the newest version of Eclipse, recreating a workspace... Nothing works, unfortunately.

Any idea?

My system:
Ubuntu 10.04 64bit, Eclipse Helios with Eclipse Webtools Platform. Java 1.6.0_22.
Apache Tomcat 6.0.14.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I figured it out.

Following steps were needed:

- New workspace
- Rightclick Project => Properties => Project Facets => Check JavaServer Faces AND JavaScript